# multithreading web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I wrote a code for getting links from web. Running this code takes about 2:20 min which is a lot since it's only a function in the code. I would like to make it more efficient. I thought about multi-threading but I have trouble understanding it deeply and applying it to this code

```
def get_manufacturer():
    manufacturers = requests.get("https://www.gsmarena.com/")
    res = re.findall(r"<li><a href=\"samsung-phones-9.php\">.+\n", manufacturers.text)
    manufacturer_links = re.findall(r"<li><a href=\"(.+?)\">", res[0])
    final_list = []
    for i in range(len(manufacturer_links)):
        final_list.append("https://www.gsmarena.com/" + manufacturer_links[i])
        # find pages
        for i in final_list:
            req = requests.get(i)
            res2 = re.findall(r"<strong>1</strong>(.+)</div>", req.text)
            for k in res2:
                if k is not None:
                    pages = re.findall(r"<a href=\"(.+?)\">.<\/a>", res2[0])
                    for j in range(len(pages)):
                        final_list.append("https://www.gsmarena.com/" + pages[j])
    return final_list
```

Comment: one bad thing that you should fix before thinking of performance is parsing html with regex. It should definitely be rewritten using a proper xml/html parsers

Comment: Also, I doubt if multithreading module does any good in this scenario (considering the effect of GIL). Using `gevent` module might help, maybe while fetching the pages from `final_list`. As for the `regex` part, there's little you can do to make it concurrent, using something like `beautifulsoup` might be a better way to pick the links.

Comment: i agree, i'm pretty new to programming so i don't know yet about all the possibilities.
anyway the parsing is not the main issue here, i guess it's the loops inside loops mostly that cause the long time

Comment: why is your code mutating a list (`final_list`) it's iterating over? this generally fails, has this function been broken while formatting in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your for loop in parallel below is an example

```
import multiprocessing as mul
```

```
def calcIntOfnth(i,ppStr,c,znot):
```

```
pool = mul.Pool(mul.cpu_count())
results = pool.starmap(calcIntOfnth, [(i,ppStr,c,znot) for i in range(k)]) # other parameters are local to this statement i.e. ppStr,c,znot,k
pool.close()
```

You'll be needed to re-write one of your for loop as a function and use `Pool` object or other similiar way to run it in parallel.

Comment: if you mind write a bit deeper explenation about this func i'll be very happy

Comment: If you mean ``calcIntOfnth`` its a wrapper of a for loop

Comment: ``for i in final_list:`` in your code can be written by a list comprehension like my code and the inner for loop can be a function and each k be passed to it